# How to return table types (collections) from procedure with sysrefcursor PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I want to return table types  with sysrefcursor in a procedure.
So i have defined record and table types:

```
create or replace TYPE "FILE_RECORD" as object 
( ID NUMBER(30,0), CREATE_DATE  TIMESTAMP(6) );

create or replace TYPE "FILE_TABLE" AS TABLE OF FILE_RECORD;

create or replace TYPE "MSG_RECORD" as object 
( ID    NUMBER(30,0), CREATE_DATE   TIMESTAMP(6) );

create or replace TYPE "MSG_TABLE" AS TABLE OF MSG_RECORD;
```

And wrote procedure:

```
   create or replace procedure file_msg
       (i_date IN date,
        o_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
    l_file FILE_TABLE;
    l_msg MSG_TABLE;

    BEGIN

      l_file := FILE_TABLE ();
      l_msg := MSG_TABLE ();

      SELECT  FILE_RECORD
             (fi.id,
              fi.create_date )
       BULK COLLECT INTO l_file
       FROM FILES fi
       WHERE fi.create_date between i_date and i_date +1;

       for i in l_file.FIRST..l_file.LAST 
          LOOP
            SELECT  MSG_RECORD
              (me.id,
               me.create_date )
            BULK COLLECT INTO l_msg
            FROM messages me
            WHERE file_id = l_file(i).id;

          END LOOP;

END file_msg;
```

So how can I now return table types l_msg and l_file with  sysrefcursor  from this procedure?

I have to return table types ( collections)  with refcursor and not columns from real tables how it is explained in  question:

> How to store result of a function which will return sysrefcursor?

what  XING suggested.
I tried  solution from that question but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store result of a function which will return sysrefcursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263749/how-to-store-result-of-a-function-which-will-return-sysrefcursor)

Comment: Solution from this topic doesn't work for my procedure.

Comment: `FILE_RECORD` and `MSG_RECORD` have the same attributes. Actually there is no need to define duplicate.

Comment: @Tom . You must edit your question stating your desired output. The answer you accepted id derived from my answer and which actually doesnot answer your question. You only asked `How to store result of a function which will return sysrefcursor?` and that has been answered in my post.

Comment: Ok, I will accept your answer as resolution, no need for editing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE file_msg (i_date   IN     DATE,
                                      o_cur     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                      P_cure    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  AS
   l_file   FILE_TABLE;
   l_msg    MSG_TABLE;
BEGIN
   l_file := FILE_TABLE ();
   l_msg := MSG_TABLE ();

   SELECT FILE_RECORD (fi.id, fi.create_date)
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_file
     FROM FILES fi
    WHERE fi.create_date BETWEEN i_date AND i_date + 1;

   Open P_cure for select * from table(l_file);

   FOR i IN l_file.FIRST .. l_file.LAST
   LOOP
      SELECT MSG_RECORD(me.id, me.create_date)
        BULK COLLECT INTO l_msg
        FROM messages me
       WHERE file_id = l_file(i).id;
   END LOOP;

   Open o_cur for select * from table(l_msg);

END file_msg;
```

Comment: Thanks , but if I want return both l_msg and l_file with refcursor how to do that?

Comment: @XING: This ref cursor o_cur will return only the last value from the FOR Loop.

Comment: @XING : Please check the edit and verify the output. The refcursor should return all the values but in your case it will always return the last value since every loop value overrides the previous one,

Comment: @AvrajitRoy . Not what logic OP used. I just showed how he can use sysrefcursor to show result of a function. Check out statement.`How to store result of a function which will return sysrefcursor?`

Comment: @XING Exactly. But this seems illogical to return only the last value for second ref cursor. Anyhow if OP's query is answred then i guess no need for further discussion :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this actually works as required.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE file_msg(
    i_date IN DATE,
    o_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    P_cure OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
  l_file FILE_TABLE;
  l_msg MSG_TABLE;
BEGIN
  l_file := FILE_TABLE ();
  l_msg  := MSG_TABLE ();
  SELECT FILE_RECORD (fi.id, fi.create_date) BULK COLLECT
  INTO l_file
  FROM FILES fi
  WHERE fi.create_date BETWEEN i_date AND i_date + 1;
  OPEN P_cure FOR SELECT                         * FROM TABLE(l_file);
  SELECT MSG_RECORD(me.id, me.create_date) BULK COLLECT
  INTO l_msg
  FROM messages me
  WHERE file_id IN
    (SELECT lv.id FROM TABLE(l_file) lv
    );
  OPEN o_cur FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_msg);
END file_msg;
/
```

Comment: It returns now all values from second cursor.